# How to interpret the GPU wattage reported by softwares?

Tags: gpu, power

To mine ETC, I'm going to split an 8-pin PCI-e connector and power an AMD RX 570 and its riser. In order for this to be completely safe for continuous use, the total power consumption of the card must be less than 150 W.

Assume that I've undervolted the GPU and softwares like GPU-z and Radeon Software report that the power is, let's say, 100 W. Can this number be trusted as a fairly accurate estimate of the **total** power consumption by the video card?